# How to change default screen layout on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, xrandr, randr, lxrandr

I tried to save my `arandr` settings to a `~/.screenlayout/default.sh` path, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu uses `LXDE` (**L**ightweight **X**11 **D**esktop **E**nvironment) which has built-in an application called `LXRandR`. It creates an autostart script for you.

To update the settings, simply run `lxrandr` in your command-line, edit your preferred screen layout and save the result.

The autostart script is saved within `~/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop`. It uses `xrandr` command to set all up. To understand how the `xrandr` command works, I recommend you to read the [ThinkWiki tutorial](https://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Xorg_RandR_1.2).

Comment: `lxrandr` was the word I was searching for, thnx.